# How to noremap plugin functions that take arguments?

Tags: functions, plugin-system, vim9

I am aware that it is good practice to map some plugin function, like for example the piece of code that follows (Vim9):

```
import autoload "../lib/my_script.vim"
noremap <unique> <script> <Plug>MyFunc :vim9cmd <SID>my_script.MyFunction()
```

to be used in user-defined scripts, e.g.

```
nnoremap <F2> <Plug>MyFunc
```

However, I am not sure how to make such a mapping when a function (in the example above `my_script.MyFunction`) also takes input arguments.

I tried something like the following:

```
import autoload "../lib/my_script.vim"
noremap <unique> <script> <Plug>MyFunc :vim9cmd <SID>my_script.MyFunction(<f-args>)
```

and then

```
nnoremap <F2> <Plug>MyFunc some_argument
```

but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of `<Plug>MyFunc` (even better, `<Plug>(MyFunc)`) is to expose a ready-made "virtual mapping" that can then be remapped at will…

- without forcing a default mapping onto the user that could conflict with their own or those from other plugins,
- without exposing the guts of your plugin, thereby allowing you to change the implementation without worries.

But it is pretty much limited to *mappings*, and mappings don't take arguments. Only functions and Ex commands do. All mappings take is a count and/or, for operators, a motion.

If you expect some arbitrary text from the user, you can create a custom Ex command, as in your comment, or you can use `:help input()` to prompt the user (see also `:help interactive-functions`):

```
nnoremap <Plug>(MyFunc) :call input(">>>")->MyFunc()<CR>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe there are no way.

My understanding of `<Plug>(Key)` is that it introduces a new virtual <kbd>Key</kbd> in your keyboard that you can used in mappings.

But these virtual keys have no parameters.

If you need parameters I suppose you need to introduce a new virtual key per parameter set.

Comment: Usch! Very convoluted. I temporary fixed it dropping  the `<Plug>` mapping but defining `command -nargs=? XYZ :call <SID>my_script.MyFunction(<f-args>)` and refer it to my `.vimrc` with `command :XYZ some_arguments` but that is calling a command inside another command... I am not sure that I like it.  Also, `command <Cmd>XYZ some_arguments` won't work either.